# How to send different SNMP Traps if eth0 is down/up?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, snmp

I would like to run a script to check if my network interface is up/down. If it is up it sends one SNMP Trap, if it is down, it sends another one.

```
ip a ||    
while read LINE; do    
  if [[ $LINE == *"2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000"* ]]; then    
    TRAP 1    
  else    
    TRAP 2
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can check if your interface is up doing: if [ -d /sys/class/net/<IFACE> ]; then <if-cmd>; else <else-cmd>; fi You can check the new status interface every second using a while loop and the sleep command.

Comment: SNMP traps are sent to my monitoring server, so I need to use them.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think you can parse the variable "LINE" inside your "while" loop, searching for the substring "state UP" and acting according to it. For example doing this: IS_UP=$(echo $LINE | grep "state UP") and then checking "IS_UP" variable. I write an answer below to give more details

Comment: The problem is that if it's down, the trap will not be sent. You could only log that or perhaps queue those traps to be sent later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
while [ 1 ]; do                                                                  
    sleep 1                                                                      
    IS_UP=$(ip a | grep "IFACE:" | grep "state UP")                              
    if [ "${IS_UP}x" == "x" ]; then                                              
        TRAP 2                                                              
    else                                                                         
        TRAP 1                                                              
    fi                                                                           
done
```

Replace IFACE for the interface of your interest. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: what´s the x for? :D

Comment: This is a common way to check if a variable contains nothing. If ${IS_UP} is empty, then "x" == "x" is true.

Comment: tnx for your help, but it¨s just outputting the "ip a" command. I replaced the IFACE with my interface name and set the trap 1 and 2(they are working by them self, but not in the script). :/

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide a working script. Please, adapt it to your own needs.